# Typescript strictNullChecks error when not possible

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I am attempting to turn on the strictNullChecks setting for my project, but have a rather curious error in the following snippet of code:

```
toasters.forEach((toster: ToasterObject) => {
  if (toaster.brandName) {
    //This line works just fine
    let y = toaster.brandName.toLowerCase() === 'test brand name';

    //This line has the error
    if (!itemsArray.some(item => item.brandName.toLowerCase() === toaster.brandName.toLowerCase())) {
        //do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

The error message has `toaster.brandName` underlined in the if statement with the following error text: `error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` If the object is fine to use on the y = line above, why would it be a problem to use in the if statement? How can I fix this so it will quit erroring on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control flow analysis is [hard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  The problem here is that the compiler does not know if or when or how a callback will be called.  So the narrowing of `toaster.brandName` from (presumably) `string | undefined` to `string` is no longer in effect inside the `array.some()` callback.  If you want to help the compiler out, you should assign the known-defined value of `toaster.brandName` to a `const`, which is expected by the compiler to always stay the same, narrow type:

```
toasters.forEach((toster: ToasterObject) => {
  if (toaster.brandName) {
    const toasterBrandName = toaster.brandName; // string, now and forever

    if (!itemsArray.some(item => item.brandName.toLowerCase() === toasterBrandName.toLowerCase())) {
        //do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. This led me to the correct answer (code in snippet above had to be massaged a bit before sharing).